# wxPython best way to pass back and forth a set of parameters from frame to dialog

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm new to wxPython programming and what I would ideally do is have parameters that can be set open in custom dialog (ParameterDialog) with text boxes that have the default values already filled in to the default parameter values set in ImageFrame. Then passing back the changed values or all values in the ParameterDialog Dialog frame by pressing OK or closing/exiting the dialog frame. What is the best way to go about this? Or is there a better solution to this than using a dialog pop-up frame.

Also I have read that modeless windows open using Show() instead of ShowModal(). Whenever I use Show(), instead of ShowModal() nothing happens. I've cut most the code out below but should give a mostly minimal example of what I want and have been able to piece together.

```
import os
import pprint
import random
import wx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import \
    FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas, \
    NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar

class ImageFrame(wx.Frame):
    """ The main frame of the application
    """
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'title')

        self.param1 = 10
        self.param2 = 0.2

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)        

        self.button_set_parameters = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Set Parameters")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_set_parameters, self.button_set_parameters)

        #
        # Layout with box sizers
        #
        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.button_set_parameters, 0, border=3, flag=flags)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.Fit(self)

    def on_set_parameters(self, event):
        dia = ParameterDialog()
        res = dia.ShowModal() # Use Show() here to allow edit window to remain open while using rest of application

        # Ideally the code below would run on ok or on closing the dialog?? Is this possible or better way to do this? Or is Checking everytime a change is made to a textbox possible and a better way?
        if res == wx.ID_CLOSE or res == wx.ID_EXIT or res == wx.ID_OK:
            self.param1 = dia.param1.GetValue()
            self.param2 = dia.param2.GetValue()
        dia.Destroy()
        return True

    def on_exit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()


class ParameterDialog(wx.Dialog):
    """
    Used to set the parameters for running.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, title="Parameters")

        self.static_text_param1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Param1:")
        # Defualt value of 10 displayed in the textbox here as param1 but would need passed in from the ImageFrame class.
        self.param1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(100, -1))        

        self.static_param2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Param2:")
        self.param2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(100, -1))        

        # Setup up Sizer
        flags = wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL
        sizer_vert =  wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sizer_horz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_horz.Add(self.static_text_param1, 0, border=3, flag=flags)
        sizer_horz.Add(self.param1, 0, border=3, flag=flags)
        sizer_vert.Add(sizer_horz, 0, flag = wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.TOP)

        sizer_horz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_horz.Add(self.static_param2, 0, border=3, flag=flags)
        sizer_horz.Add(self.param2, 0, border=3, flag=flags)
        sizer_vert.Add(sizer_horz, 0, flag = wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.BOTTOM)

        self.SetSizer(sizer_vert)
        sizer_vert.Fit(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    app.frame = ImageFrame()
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: any way you can make the example shorter?  Even though you say you have edited it down people (including me) might not be willing to read that much code.

Comment: @tcaswell - I removed almost everything except the parameter passing between the dialog and the frame. and I still draw the figure but that is about all I left in. I hope that is minimal enough. I can remove drawing the figure if you think that is better so I only have the parameter passing.

Comment: @tcaswell - A lot of the code is just setting up the sizers as well. The core code of interest is maybe 10-15 lines.

Comment: Then show only the 10-15 interesting lines with the _bare minimum_ of infrastructure around them.  Do the sizers affect anything about the parameter passing?  Does the plotting affect anything about the parameter passing?  See http://sscce.org/

Comment: @tcaswell - I've updated it but think I got it sorted. I just ended up making a parameter class. Passing the parameter class in and modifying the values if the user saves or hits ok in the dialog. Then destroying the dialog after hitting save. Not sure if this is the best way or most pythonic way.

Comment: If you solved it, please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the values using what you have already:

```
self.param1 = dia.param1.GetValue()
```

However, this only works when you are showing the dialog modally. When you show a dialog modally, it blocks the main loop of your application and creates a new main loop for the dialog. Then when the dialog exits, you can grab the values using the code above before you Destroy the dialog.

If you don't want to use a modal dialog or just want to try doing it a slightly different way, I would recommend giving pubsub a try. It uses the Publish/Subscribe model where you set up one or more listeners and then publish messages to said listeners. Here a link to a simple tutorial: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/